# wso2 esb how to increase endpoint timeout

Tags: timeout, wso2-esb

I have JMS queue message processor sequence where request is send to SOAP endpoint. However request to this endpoint can take a long time, up to 30 minutes or so. How can I can configure ESB to allow long timeout values ? Currently I'm getting following error after 60 seconds:

```
[2014-01-20 14:18:31,772]  WARN - TargetHandler http-outgoing-4: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE
[2014-01-20 14:18:31,775]  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:c6a023c2-7fb4-4321-b1c2-d78e9bb13add But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

Thanks for any help

**Edit: I added http.socket.timeout=1800000 -property in repository/conf/passthru-http.properties which seems to solve the timeout issue.**

Comment: I know this is off topic and I'll probably get downvoted, but blocking on http for 30 minutes is almost always a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a "Scheduled Message Forwarding Processor", to increase the send timeout up to 30 minutes :

1. In your **endpoint**, verify that "connection timeout" is **"never
   timeout"** (edit the endpoint in the console and "Show Advanced
   options")
2. Edit **repository/conf/synapse.properties** and modify
   **synapse.global_timeout_interval** (in ms) : this is the maximum time a
   callback instance will exist in wso2 to receive the response
3. copy the sample **axis2 conf file**
   from samples/axis2Client/client_repo/conf/axis2.xml to, for example,
   repository/conf/axis2/axis2_mp.xml
4. Edit this axis2_mp.xml config, find
   **transportSender name="http"** and add a **parameter "SO_TIMEOUT"** (in ms) : `<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT" locked="false">108000000</parameter>`
5. Edit your Message Processor and in **Show Additional Parameters**, specify the entry "**Axis2 Configuration**" to repository/conf/axis2/axis2_mp.xml

SO_TIMEOUT is the time to wait for the response.
You can specify CONNECTION_TIMEOUT for the max time to establish the connection.

Pay attention : **all** callbacks will persist up to 30 minutes in the ESB !

Comment: Thanks, Actually I'm using "Message Sampling Processor", where Send -mediator is used to call SOAP Endpoint.

Comment: Yes changing **synapse.global_timeout_interval** and adding **http.socket.timeout=1800000** -property in repository/conf/passthru-http.properties seems to solve the problem.